# roscpp: set / get vector containing infinity from parameter server

Tags: ros-melodic, rosparam, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I would to read a vector containing some infinity components from the ROS parameter server. I have included the following line in the roslaunch:

```
<rosparam param="my_vector">[0.0, inf, 0.0]</rosparam>
```

Using the command line `rosparam get` tool, the vector seems to be loaded correctly in the parameter server, but trying to read it from my node with the following lines:

```
std::vector<double> v;
ros::param::get("my_vector", v);
```

returns `false`.

Is there any built-in way to set / get an infinity value from the parameter server?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363807/roscpp:-set-/-get-vector-containing-infinity-from-parameter-server/) by [d.fenucci](https://answers.ros.org/users/24372/d.fenucci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2020-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Shouldn't it be `.inf` instead? Your `v` is a `vector<double>`.

Related: #q275681.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [d.fenucci](https://answers.ros.org/users/24372/d.fenucci/) on 2020-10-20**:
Yes, that works! Many thanks